# In Netty5, if I have channelID string, how to get the Channel?

Tags: netty, channel

I store the channelID String into channelGroup, but later i need get the channel to write out some into to client. How to get the channel if I can get the channelID string? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need the ChannelId object and then use ChannelGroup.find(ChannelId).